# How to check if sequelize model matches database table?

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

Is there a way to check if a [Sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/) model matches the database table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find anything that would do this so I created [sequelizr](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelizr) which can create models for Sequelize and check that the models match the tables.

To do this I forked [sequelize-auto](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize-auto) and created a wrapper to be able to execute in a terminal.

You can run `npx sequelizr check [args]` to check if your database table layouts have changed then you can run `npx sequelizr download [args]` to update the models.